# New site design!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/updated-site-design-for-english-language-learners-community).

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL) and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin) theme!

Comment: Hah, I was lost in the site for 15 minutes. It looks so much different.

Comment: The gift of the year! #Kudos!

Comment: Hooray! Much gratitude!

Comment: Looks pretty spiffy to me.  :)

Comment: Just noticed the new icon in the hot network questions. Congratulations, ELL!

Comment: The abstraction of using the bookmark as the icon is a bit hard to fathom, but certainly a bright and distinct icon...so it has that going for it.With the bookmark now taking center stage, it might help to contextualize it more if the stylized "E" as two books just became a solid viewed-from-the-cover literal book graphic (flattish) with the bookmark sticking out of the pages, to help people make the connection.  It would assist with the drop-cap EEnglish concerns mentioned below as well.

Comment: 18 months on, shouldn't this now be tagged *status-completed*?

Answer (score 34):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The icon on the tour page and the smaller icons have been updated, they will be live after our next production build.

---

Not really a bug report, just expressing my surprise.

I'm surprised the [tour page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) shows only the bookmark, with no dictionaries. That is, I thought the artwork would resemble the button on the right, but instead it shows the button on the left:

[image]

*I think it would be nice to get that E on the Tour page*.

Also, it would be nice if that E were incorporated as the tiny symbol used in the SE pulldown (perhaps sans bookmark, if it's too hard to read it with a bookmark):

[image]

If we switched to the E, the logo would look like both an E, and a stack of dictionaries. As it stands now, when an ELL question appears in a list of Hot Questions, it really doesn't resemble much of anything:

[image]

Comment: I'd also say I like the E more.

Comment: @wythagoras - It appears that [we are not alone](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/bookmark-in-favicon-is-small-and-the-circle-blends-into-backgrounds-too-easily) in this regard.

Comment: I think if there was one version of the logo specific for small icons (with a larger favicon relative to the E) ti could work. It might have to take up more than a half of the width of the E.

Comment: The E logo with the bookmark looks like a waiter with a napkin folded over his arm to me!

Comment: Oh, the E is a book? That's a bookmark? Never would have figured that out. Was wondering why someone put a ribbon on the E.

Comment: @DCShannon - Well, it's actually two books, one atop the other, as was explained in the initial [Design Concept](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/updated-site-design-for-english-language-learners-community).

Comment: I agree with @Lucky's [cherry-on-the-cake comment](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/bookmark-in-favicon-is-too-small-and-the-circle-blends-into-backgrounds-too-easi/2967#comment6823_2967). So long as our notifications are depicted with the end of a bookmark, I'm a little disappointed this has been labeled as `status completed`.

Comment: "As it stands now, when an ELL question appears in a list of Hot Questions, it really doesn't resemble much of anything" - my thoughts exactly. I had no idea why is the ELL symbol now a flag ribbon instead of the ELL letters that were there originally. (And even now that I know the reason - and that it's not actually a flag ribbon - I don't understand it anyway.)

Comment: @JanuaryFirst-of-May - [It is what it is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtwf.png). This issue has sat dormant for awhile now; I'm afraid we're stuck with our [Lincoln Logs chimney](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kKvswQa2pZ0/ToJSWvd26UI/AAAAAAAAClM/DfOxdyvpttQ/s1600/chimney2.gif).

Answer (score 12):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

---

[image: full title logo]

The shape on the left looks like a drop-cap E, so the word looks like the site is "Eenglish."  I couldn't even figure out what the dictionaries were supposed to be until Wendikidd told me. I think it would be better to go with the drop-cap, but if not please add some page lines to make it clear the dictionaries are supposed to be books that resemble a letter, not an actual letter.

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea what that was. That's actually why I'm reading this thread, to figure out what that logo is. And the medals, what are... those are ribbons... oh, bookmarks. Also bookmarks? Where did this come from?

Comment: It does look like "EENGLISH" to me.

Comment: I'm not going to lie I think the E looks absolutely terrible. It floats between dictionaries and a childish "E." it doesn't commit to either one and suffers for it. The rest of the site looks great but the E sticks out like a sore, sore thumb. I think it needs to be filled in with yellowish pages or something and committed more fully toward looking like books with an E inspiration, rather than something that looks like it took two minutes to make in Illustrator

Comment: I like it personally.  I didn't see it as looking like another E.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

In the **Select your next badge** section, when the badges are in progress we can able to see the bronze and silver badges but the gold badge is not visible like the reaming badges due to the color transparency. Hope this need to be fix.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Badge icon not visible properly]

---

After the new [UI Change for the profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/2451726), this display issue has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: New badge icons with better visibility]

Comment: This seems to have been solved with the (global) new design of the profile page.

Comment: @Glorfindel : Thanks. When verifying this issue, I found another [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297801/312043)

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
This should be fixed after the next production build, #bringbackoursidebar

---

The sidebar has decided it doesn't fit on the side, and has instead moved down below the posts.
[image: top of ELL main page]
[image: middle of ELL main page]

This is on Firefox 44.0.2 (OS is Windows 7).

Chrome looks OK. IE11 is fine if I'm not logged in, but looks exactly like Firefox as soon as I log in. (It's possible Firefox also works if you're not logged in, but I ain't logging out to check.) And like Colleen said, this is only for the main pages - if you open a question, the sidebar is up where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for the report! We're looking into it.

Comment: Repro on Firefox 43.0.4 on Ubuntu, but it looks okay on Chrome.

Comment: Also a problem on IE 11 on the main page, but the layout is fine when I click on a question.

Comment: The review page also has the same problem.

Comment: When will the next production build go live?

Comment: Never mind, I see that it's already in place. Yay, I can haz sidebar!

Comment: +1 for personifying the sidebar

Comment: @OldBunny2800: I take it you're not a developer? As anyone who has wrestled with CSS can tell you, you don't need to assign a personality to these things: they come with personalities built-in. Generally ornery, sometimes downright evil personalities.

Comment: No, I code as a pastime, but I usually would say "the sidebar is off" or "my code is not working, gimmetehcodez"

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The icons have been updated, they will be live after our next production build.

---

This design bug was posted as a separate question on meta; I wanted to place it here so that it would come to the design team's attention, as I agree wholeheartedly. (And thank you for being awesome; the design as a whole is incredible, and you have ELL's thanks!)

Link to design bug post: [Bookmark in favicon is too small and the circle blends into backgrounds too easily](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/bookmark-in-favicon-is-small-and-the-circle-blends-into-backgrounds-too-easily)

The overall gist of the post is that the tiny icon that appears for ELL when you click the left sidebar is much smaller than on other sites, and that the gray circle is very different than the style of other icons. OP requests either the orange bookmark only, without the circle, or the E dictionary with the orange bookmark (I support the second option, but the first would also be an improvement).

Thanks!

Comment: I, too, hope the design team implements the second option. By itself, it looks more like a chimney than a bookmark. (Interestingly enough, I don't mind the bookmark ends being used as badge logos, because they also resemble the end of a [ribbon on a gold seal](http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/416/gold-medal-ribbon-416600.jpg), so they are quite apropos for that. I hope the badges stay as is, but I'm looking forward to favicon being revised.)

Answer (score 6):

In the tradition of manuscripts and early typeset texts with large ornamental capitals, couldn't the ornamental E be made a part of the word, so that it served more than a decorative function? I find the EE a little disturbing.

[image]

I would also like to see the title of questions in a little darker hue. I find the current color too pale:

[image]

It's a strain to read after a while. Not enough contrast.

P.S. Sub-pixel font-rendering technology works poorly with low-saturation colors (pastels).  A pale teal for a text font is a poor choice from the point of view of legibility. This complaint cannot be dismissed as merely a matter of personal taste. Just the opposite is true -- the current design gives the personal aesthetic of the designer primacy over legibility.

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2956? (They're asking for the same design change to be made, based on most of the same observations.)

Comment: The rationales given for the desired change are quite different, and I show an image of what I'm talking about in terms of a revised design; in that respect they're different as well.

Comment: FWIW, the "Double E" hasn't bothered me at all. That said, I wouldn't consider this a step in the wrong direction. I like this version, too.

Answer (score 4):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

---

When I link to the site from chat, it shows the old beta-style header:

[image: links to sites from chat]

But as you can see, when I link to EL&U from chat, I get a snazzy EL&U custom design header.

Will we get snazzy chat links for ELL, too? :-)

Comment: That should already be in place: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bvG5c.png. You may need to hard-refresh the page, though.

Comment: Yep, when I look at that post in chat, the ELL header is all snazzy, too.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

The new logo/icons are not yet updated in the Stack Exchange site, it still showing the old logo/icons. Those are need to be update.

Sample screenshot from top and accounts section:

[image: top section]

[image: ELL old logo]

---

Those icons were updated correctly in the Stack Exchange site.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: New icons were updated]

Answer (score 1):

I really like the site's design, but I'd like to know what the significance of the "E" and the bookmark is. I imagine the bookmark has something to do with learning, i.e. marking a page that is useful.

Comment: The rationale behind the design is explained in Stéphane Martin's [other meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/updated-site-design-for-english-language-learners-community). If you want to see how the design evolved, I'd recommend scrolling down, and then starting at the header that reads **Design Concept**. That should answer most of your questions.