# Bookmark in favicon is too small and the circle blends into backgrounds too easily

Tags: feature-request, design

I double-checked, and the favicon didn't make it into the design preview, or I would (hopefully) have commented on this earlier. But the bookmark is about the only thing really visible on most backgrounds in notifications, site switcher, and so forth: the gray circle just blends in, making it look remarkably small compared to almost all other favicons. For example:
[image: Screenshot of favicon alongside RPG, Space, and Stack Overflow's favicons]

I can see two ways to address this. One is to drop the circle and just make it a bookmark that fills most of the available space. That would be fairly straightforward. The other would be to use the entire E/bookmark logo; I assume this was rejected for whatever reason, although I'd thought it would be reasonable enough. If possible, I'd prefer this choice, I think. An extremely crude rendition, just for general idea:

[image: Hacked-up resized logo]

Or with others:
[image: Resized logo favicon alongside RPG, Space, and Stack Overflow's favicons]

I think that has a better heft to it (although the line weight got reduced too much by my crude hackery).

Anyway, thanks for a design I generally like!

Comment: A great design! Grey colour doesn't blend well with white. A more darker grey would have been better. Also, A more sharp vermilion would look even better. Personal view!

Comment: I agree with you. Not only is the favicon small, the bookmark by itself doesn't have much meaning, either, especially in, say, a list of [Hot Network Questions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eiapU.png). That E would be so much more apropos!

Comment: I'm 100% with you and @J.R. on this: what's a bookmark without a book? It doesn't look good on its own, and it's the first thing users see when coming from other SE networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons have been updated (bigger bookmark to match other icons' size), they will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Is it still going to be just a bookmark? Or will it be the bookmark in the E? (There seems to be a lot of support for the latter...)

Comment: @J.R.: For now, it looks like just the plain bookmark.

Comment: I hope that will change. I'll be quite disappointed if that's the final look for ELL.

Comment: A bigger bookmark is more visible, so it is an improvement, but it is quite plain compared to other SE websites' logos. Also, you can't really tell it's a bookmark when it's on its own. The rest of the design is great, but the icons with the books would really be a cherry on the cake :-).

Comment: Hey! This hasn't been changed yet on the Chat server, which still has the smaller button on the white background.

Comment: @Stéphane - I'm wondering if you are following [this meta discussion](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/more-places-for-the-e-instead-of-bookmark).