# Is it possible to change the font of THIS site?

Tags: discussion, font

My question is very simple. This site has a default font which is kind of boring. See the font of the other English site:

[image]

Is it possible to change the font of THIS site (https://ell.stackexchange.com/) to the one the other English site uses?

Comment: Somethings are more useful when they are simple. The current font increases readability. It's easier to read. Personally, I don't find the font boring. IMO the design of ELL is actually better than that of EL&U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be boring, but it's also familiar, and easy to read...

It looks like the font wasn't discussed during site design and feedback: [UPDATED: Site design for English Language Learners community](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2912/18673). Actually, it looks like most of the newest site designs (yes, ELL is one of them, even though it already exists for four and a half years) don't use custom fonts. There is some discussion on Meta Stack Exchange about fonts, e.g. [Fonts and the new Q&A theming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311033/295232) and [Bring back site-specific fonts to the new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317239/295232). [This answer about font requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307865/295232) may also be worth reading.

There is always the option to use a stylesheet manager like [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) to customize the site; changing the font should require only one line of CSS:

```
body, p, div, span, a { font-family: "Comic Sans MS" !important }
```

That produces the following result:

[image]